# Displaying a $result as a result for a Search

Tags: php, mysql

I have recently completed my search engine but now I have a new challenge.

This following code I am using it to read out values from a callflow table in my DB and displaying them in a table letting u know wether the call was answered yes or no.

```
  if(isset($res))
        {
            //creating table
            echo '<table style="width:1500px; cell-padding:4px; cell-spacing:0; margin:auto;">';       
            echo'<th>Time</th><th>Answered Y/N</th></th><th>Naam</th><th>Caller ID</th>'; 

           while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
            {
              echo '<tr>';

              echo '<td>'.$result['statusCalling'].'</td>';
              if ($result['statusAnswered'] =="NULL"||$result['statusAnswered'] =="Null" || $result['statusAnswered'] =="null" || $result['statusAnswered'] =="")
      {
      echo "<td>Not Answered!</td>";
      }
    else
      {
      echo "<td>Answered!</td>";
      }
              echo '<td>'.$result['calleridname'].'</td>'.'<td>'.$result['calleridnum'].'</td>' ;
              echo '</tr>';
            }
            echo '</table>';
        }
```

I need now to display these results in a search engine result!
I tried this but I doesnt work! No idea how else to go about this! Please help!

```
$output = '';
//collect
if(isset($_POST['asd']))  {
 $searchq = $_POST['search'];
 $searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$searchq);
  $query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM callflow WHERE statusCalling LIKE "%'.$searchq.'%" OR calleridname LIKE "%'.$searchq.'%" OR calleridnum LIKE "%'.$searchq.'%" OR $results LIKE "%'.$searchq'%"');
  $count = mysql_num_rows($query);
 if($count == 0) {
  $output = 'There was no search results!';
 }else{
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
   $statusCalling = $row['statusCalling'];
   $calleridname = $row['calleridname'];
   $calleridnum = $row['calleridnum'];
   $results = $row['statusAnswered'];
   $id = $row['ID'];
   $output .= '<div>'.$statusCalling.' '.$calleridname.' '.$calleridnum.' '.$results.'</div>';
  }
  }
}
```

I know that mysql is deprecated, I am learning to program still and i figure if I don't know mysql I cant learn pdo because I don't understand what is what. Please help!

Comment: If u don't want to help than why waste your time spamming here? I did not ask for you opinion about what you think I should learn or use. I need to learn to write script and understand the why's and how's. So If  I don't know something in mysql I ask it! Else how do you expect me to learn mysqli or pdo if they are all improved versions of mysql? Like I said. If u don't want to help don't waste my or your time and just ignore this question.

Comment: @KentjeAtWork Your attitude is exactly the wrong one a good developer should have. You have to be prepared to listen to people when they're telling you that you're doing something wrong, not take it as a personal insult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked out the answer and I am posting it here so others can see a way of solving this when they researching for something similar.

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Could not connect");
mysql_select_db("voizxl_wachtrij") or die("Could not find Database");

$output = '';
//collect
if(isset($_POST['asd']))  {
    $searchq = $_POST['search'];
    $searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$searchq);
  $query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM callflow WHERE statusCalling LIKE "%'.$searchq.'%" OR calleridname LIKE "%'.$searchq.'%" OR calleridnum LIKE "%'.$searchq.'%"');
  $count = mysql_num_rows($query);
    if($count == 0) {
        $output = 'There was no search results!';
    }else{
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
            $statusCalling = $row['statusCalling'];
            $calleridname = $row['calleridname'];
            $calleridnum = $row['calleridnum'];
            $id = $row['ID'];
            $output[] = $row;
        }
        }
}   
?> 

<?php foreach($output as $o){;
                 if($o['statusAnswered']){


                 echo $o['statusCalling'].' Answered: '.$o['calleridname'].' '.$o['statusAnswered'].' '.$o['calleridnum'].'<br />';

                 }else{
                 echo $o['statusCalling'].' Not Answered: '.$o['calleridname'].' '.$o['calleridnum'].'<br/>';
                 }

              }?>

               <br/><br/><br/>
    <?php
```

Cheers